# How to fix int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' when doing Video Processing? (Object Detection)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, video-processing

I am really new to Deep Learning so excuse my lack of knowledge in the field.
So basically I am  trying to test my trained model .pb with a video stream. Here is the code that I am using to do this.

```
# Import packages
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import sys

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")

# Import utilites
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()

# Path to frozen detection graph .pb file, which contains the model that is used
# for object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = 'C:/path/folder/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# Path to label map file
PATH_TO_LABELS = 'C:/path/folder/label_map.pbtxt'

# Path to video
PATH_TO_VIDEO = 'C:/path/folder/video.MP4'

# Number of classes the object detector can identify
NUM_CLASSES = 1

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

# Load the Tensorflow model into memory.
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

    sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)

# Define input and output tensors (i.e. data) for the object detection classifier

# Input tensor is the image
image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

# Output tensors are the detection boxes, scores, and classes
# Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected
detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')

# Each score represents level of confidence for each of the objects.
# The score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')

# Number of objects detected
num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

video = cv2.VideoCapture(PATH_TO_VIDEO)

while(video.isOpened()):

    # Acquire frame and expand frame dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    # i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
    ret, frame = video.read()
    frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)

    # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
        [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
        feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})

    # Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        frame,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=8,
        min_score_thresh=0.80)

    # All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.
    cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)

    # Press 'q' to quit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# Clean up
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Everything is doing ok, I can run it and I see the video stream open up and even see the boxes drawn on the detected objects nicely.
However after 1-2 seconds the program stops and quits with the following error:

```
np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

I have no idea how to going around solving this problem, because in the error I don't even understand what program it is talking about since my program only has like a 100 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Add these linee

```
    if ret == False:
         break
```

You are getting the error because you are running out of frame and frame becomes None.

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(PATH_TO_VIDEO)

while(video.isOpened()):

    # Acquire frame and expand frame dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    # i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if ret == False:
         break
    frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)

    # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
        [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
        feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})

    # Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        frame,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=8,
        min_score_thresh=0.80)

    # All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.
    cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)

    # Press 'q' to quit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# Clean up
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. So now the error does not show anymore. but unfortunately the video still closes after 1-2 seconds. ```2020-03-31 09:19:31.680308: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/redzone_allocator.cc:312] Internal: Invoking ptxas not supported on Windows
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. This message will be only logged once.
2020-03-31 09:19:31.706387: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_100.dll ``` This is what cmd says now.

Comment: 1. Because, your video is short 2. That's a warning, which is very common. I think your error is fixed. Accept/ Upvote the answer if it helps.

Comment: My video is 1-2 minutes long, so no it's not short, the program still closes so my problem is not fixed

Comment: In that case does your video runs way faster or it just breaks in the middle?

Comment: It runs at normal speed, and the programs stops after like 1 second, don't even have time to move the window.

Comment: You are using the default VideoCapture with buffer right? Is your model too slow? There is two reasons for this 1) there was internal ffmpeg error and your video had some issues so it broke, but it should throw some error. 2) your model is too slow, and you have no buffer so you are running out of frames. Maybe post your full code with full error message in the question.

Comment: ok I see, however excuse my lack of knowledge as I am new in this field. I cannot tell which of the 2 could it be. I have updated the full code in the quesiton

Comment: I think you posted the old error. Are you still facing the same error?

Comment: No sorry, by adding your code snippet, that error went away but, the video still closes so that 'error' still remains